# wget: How to preserve folder structure to a certain level?

Tags: bash, wget, xargs

I need to download all contents from buckets on public google storage. Recursive downloading does not work with wget as far as I know (I know it does with the APIs and gsutil but I need a wget solution).
However, I do have a list with the URLs of the folder contents.
The goal is to preserve the folder structure from a certain entrypoint, folder1, as follows:

```
http://storage.googleapis.com/publicdataset/bla/bla/.../folder1/subfolder1/file1.txt
-folder1
--subfolder1
---file1
---file2
---subfolder2
----file3
```

One way is using the -r parameter. While no recursive downloading will happen since we're downloading from buckets rather than folders, the folder structure is inherited from the URL. This can be extended by -nH (removes the host name) and --cut-dirs=n (removes all directory levels higher than n).
However, the number of dirs to cut changes depending how many levels below folder1 the file is located. So I would need the inverse of cut-dirs, counting levels from the host URL.

Downloading all files on the list should run in parallel using xargs ($LINKS is the path to the file containing all download links, one file per line):

```
echo $LINKS | xargs -n 1 -P 8 wget -r
```

The $LINKS file looks like this:

```
http://storage.googleapis.com/publicdataset/bla/bla/.../folder1/subfolder1/file1.txt
http://storage.googleapis.com/publicdataset/bla/bla/.../folder1/subfolder1/file2.txt
http://storage.googleapis.com/publicdataset/bla/bla/.../folder1/subfolder1/subfolder2/file3.txt
```

What I have thought of so far is dynamically creating the download location from each link. I do not know if it's possible to do that in the above line, as the output of echo would need to be piped to wget in it's original format and again after being modified by awk/sed.

Comment: `However, the number of dirs to cut changes depending how many levels below folder1 the file is located.` So just extract that information from the url and cut that many. `I do not know if it's possible to do that in the above line` What is the content of "LINKS" variable?

Comment: The $LINKS variable is a text file containing one download link (file) per line. I will edit the post to highligh that.

Comment: You can `xargs -n1 bash -c 'levels=$(some script "$1" some script); wget -r --cur-dirs="$levels" "$1"' _` or even export a bash function and run it. Can you instead of describing, rather post the content of LINKS variable? Code speaks 1000 words.

Comment: Thanks you! I will try to wrap my head around that.

Comment: AFAIK --cut-dirs removes the number of directories starting from the beginnig (after host name), and does exactly what you need. See https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#index-cut-directories

Comment: Thanks again to both of you. @KamilCuk I piped a somewhat awkward chain of cut/rev/cut/rev to get a folder structure that I then used to specify the output directory. That's probably cleaner, as wget doesn't try to do recursion where it actually shouldn't. 
I actually fell over my feet missing the _ at the end of the command. May I ask what it does?

Comment: @dr_agon You are completely right, thank you! How did I even confuse that?